# Relations tables in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are two tables: `user` and `order`:

```
create_table "orders" do | t |
t.text "name"
t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "users" do | t |
t.text "email"
end
```

Two classes:

```
class Order <ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to: users
end

class User <ActiveRecord :: Base
   has_many: orders
end
```

Сontroller:

```
class TestController <ApplicationController
   def index
     @ tmp = Order.all(:include =>:users)
   end
end
```

Question: I need all orders but instead of `user_id` the `email` associated with the `user_id` is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, I'm new to Rails myself but try this:

```
@tmp = Order.all(
              :select => 'orders.id, orders.etc, users.email',
              :joins => "LEFT JOIN users on users.id = orders.user_id",
              # :conditions => ['column_name = ?', @value_of_your_choice],
              :order => 'orders.created_at ASC'
            )
```

You could also try this:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tmp = Order.all()
  end
end
```

Then, in the view:

```
<% @tmp.each do |order| %>

  <!-- do not show if orders.user.id is NULL -->
  <% if !order.user_id.nil? %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= order.id %></td>
      <td><%= order.user.email %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Since the relations between the two models are defined, you can access the properties of the associated person in this way.

You might need to change the `belongs_to: users` to `belongs_to: user` in `user.rb` though

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 
in some cases orders table user_id is nil, in line  
<% = order.user.email%>
falls mistake, as it is to get around?

Comment: do you mean some orders have a `NULL` value in the  `user_id` column? What would you like to do with those, not show them the user? I will update the answer

Comment: Yeah, how do I get around in view?

Comment: Just to point out, the `.all` method and the hash style of queries is deprecated. The preferred method is to use the active record relation methods, such as `.select`, `.joins` and `.order`. For example, rewritten, your query would look like `@tmp = Order.select('orders.id, orders.etc, users.email').joins("LEFT JOIN users on users.id = orders.user_id").order('orders.created_at ASC')`

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation to comment, but about the order.user.email issue, use the try method:

```
order.user.try(:email)
```

If the user is nil, it just return nil, instead of raising a exception.